# How do you mock a module-scoped variable in Jest?

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, mocking

Consider the following function:

```
let dictionary = {
  there: "there"
}

function sayHi(word){
  if (dictionary.hasOwnProperty(word)){
    return "hello " + dictionary[word] 
  }
}
```

If I wanted to test the `sayHi` function, how would I mock the `dictionary` variable in a Jest test?

I've tried importing everything from the module and overwriting the dictionary object but that hasn't worked, likewise I've tried mocking it as a function, but still can't get it to work.

Comment: You don't, in short. If you consider dictionary a collaborator of sayHi, rather than just an implementation detail, move it out of the module.

Comment: Hi @jonrsharpe, thank you for your comment. I will see if I can organise the code differently.

Comment: In this case it seems to be static data, so I'd just treat it as an implementation detail.

Comment: Hi @jonrsharpe, sorry to be ignorant, but how would I do that within a test?

Comment: You don't have to do anything particular, that's the point. You test e.g. `expect(sayHi("there")).toEqual("there")` and don't think too much about whether there's an object mapping or a switch or a bunch of ifs or just `const sayHi = () => "there"`.

Comment: Hmm, the problem is, when I just call sayHi I get a "undefined has no property hasOwnProperty" error

Comment: Not with what you've posted. If you're still having a problem, give a [mre].

Comment: Ok thanks, I’ll update the code

Answer (score 0):

You can use [rewire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rewire) package to override variables within the module.

E.g.

`index.js`:

```js
let dictionary = {
  there: 'there',
};

function sayHi(word) {
  if (dictionary.hasOwnProperty(word)) {
    return 'hello ' + dictionary[word];
  }
}

module.exports = { sayHi };
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
const rewire = require('rewire');

describe('67044925', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const mod = rewire('./');
    mod.__set__('dictionary', { there: 'teresa teng' });
    const actual = mod.sayHi('there');
    expect(actual).toEqual('hello teresa teng');
  });

  it('should pass too', () => {
    const mod = rewire('./');
    mod.__set__('dictionary', { there: 'slideshowp2' });
    const actual = mod.sayHi('there');
    expect(actual).toEqual('hello slideshowp2');
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  examples/67044925/index.test.js (12.148 s)
  67044925
    ✓ should pass (15 ms)
    ✓ should pass too (4 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        14.047 s
```

Comment: *"Just because you can, doesn't mean you should."* Reaching inside the module boundary breaches encapsulation, `dictionary` (particularly in your example where it's clearly not exported) is effectively _private_ to the module.